# difference between network address and subnet address

Tags: subnet

Now this question seems a bit childish to ask, but since i am new to networking, so i think i should ask the question here. while studying about subnetting, i was trying to understand a subnet mask, let's say we are given with this class C i.p address  192.168.0.13 with subnet mask 255.255.255.224=27. now they are asking to find the "network address". My confusion begins with the term "network address" . Does it mean the address of the base network? that is 192.168.0.0?(since it is a class C ip), or does it mean it is asking for the "sub net" address, which would be i think applying the 27 bit wise AND operation with the ip address(although the result remains unchanged since it is a class C ip, but for CIDR cases, definitely the "base network address", and "subnet address " must would differ.).However my question is are "network address" and "subnet address" same? most likely not as per my understanding, i am confused because they are using these two term interchangeably. Also if they are different ,that means we will only be able to determine the address of the "sub net address" from a given ip and subnet mask pair, in that case how would the internet protocol determine the base network address in which a given ip belongs? do we need additional information for that?

Comment: Note that network classes were obsoleted by CIDR in 1993 - please leave them dead and buried. With CIDR, "network address" and "subnet address" are identical.

Comment: well let us assume the ip is classless, I have written only because it is easily understandable